# How to Validate JSON from API with php

Tags: php, json, validation

I am creating a JSON feed using the following code:

```
<?
class gapi {
    public $secret = 'YOUR_APPLICATION_KEY';
    public $url = "https://rest.gadventures.com";

    public function Get($res='tours') {
        $header = array('Accept: application/json', "X-Application-Key: $this->secret");
        // Note: when using the POST or PUT methods, you must add the header "Content-Type: application/json"
        $url = $this->url . '/' . $res;
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        // Workaround to access SSL server and slide in through side door
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        // Hide curl response
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $result;
    }
}

$gapi = new gapi();

// Get Peru Panorama dossier
$dossier = json_decode($gapi->Get('tour_dossiers/21346'));

// output entire object
var_dump($dossier);
?>
```

The feed is sadly not valid though, does anyone know of a way to make the output valid?

This is my Parse Results Error

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
array(17) { ["id"] 
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Does anyone know how to remove the odd array(#)'s from the json so it will be valid?

**Solution provided by RiggsFolly**

Replacing the

```
var_dump($dossier);
```

with

```
print_r($gapi->Get('tour_dossiers/21346'));
```

Exported the data to print as the json array properly.

Comment: Show us a `print_r($gapi->Get('tour_dossiers/21346'));` so we can see what is actually being returned by the curl call. Just a sample of it will do if its big. Oh and edit the question with this data, dont put it in a comment

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly that worked perfectly.
I've updated my post with your solution.

Thanks tons for the quick support :)